# Display images of different formats from base64 from backend api - angular 7

Tags: angular, image, typescript, angular7

I'm having an api where I'll get image in base64 format, it can in any of the formats(.png, .jpg, .svg etc...).

I want to display the images in my application using:

```
  <img *ngIf="imageBase64" [src]="imageBase64 ? ('data:image/svg+xml ;base64,' +imageBase64 | safe) : ''" alt="" />
```

How can I display images in different formats in the best way possible.

Thanks in advance.

Example

```
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4NCjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgd2lkdGg9IjEyMzUiIGhlaWdodD0iNjUwIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNzQxMCAzOTAwIj4NCjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI3NDEwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjM5MDAiIGZpbGw9IiNiMjIyMzQiLz4NCjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wLDQ1MEg3NDEwbTAsNjAwSDBtMCw2MDBINzQxMG0wLDYwMEgwbTAsNjAwSDc0MTBtMCw2MDBIMCIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjZmZmIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjMwMCIvPg0KPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjI5NjQiIGhlaWdodD0iMjEwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzNjM2I2ZSIvPg0KPGcgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZiI+DQo8ZyBpZD0iczE4Ij4NCjxnIGlkPSJzOSI+DQo8ZyBpZD0iczUiPg0KPGcgaWQ9InM0Ij4NCjxwYXRoIGlkPSJzIiBkPSJNMjQ3LDkwIDMxNy41MzQyMzAsMzA3LjA4MjAzOSAxMzIuODczMjE4LDE3Mi45MTc5NjFIMzYxLjEyNjc4MkwxNzYuNDY1NzcwLDMwNy4wODIwMzl6Ii8+DQo8dXNlIHhsaW5rOmhyZWY9IiNzIiB5PSI0MjAiLz4NCjx1c2UgeGxpbms6aHJlZj0iI3MiIHk9Ijg0MCIvPg0KPHVzZSB4bGluazpocmVmPSIjcyIgeT0iMTI2MCIvPg0KPC9nPg0KPHVzZSB4bGluazpocmVmPSIjcyIgeT0iMTY4MCIvPg0KPC9nPg0KPHVzZSB4bGluazpocmVmPSIjczQiIHg9IjI0NyIgeT0iMjEwIi8+DQo8L2c+DQo8dXNlIHhsaW5rOmhyZWY9IiNzOSIgeD0iNDk0Ii8+DQo8L2c+DQo8dXNlIHhsaW5rOmhyZWY9IiNzMTgiIHg9Ijk4OCIvPg0KPHVzZSB4bGluazpocmVmPSIjczkiIHg9IjE5NzYiLz4NCjx1c2UgeGxpbms6aHJlZj0iI3M1IiB4PSIyNDcwIi8+DQo8L2c+DQo8L3N2Zz4=
```

The above is a base64 format of .svg file.

so in src property binding if I give `data:image/svg+xml`, it will work, I need a generic format to print image even if it is png format etc...

like `data:image/svg+xml/png/jpg` etc... which is not working

Comment: What format is the variable `imageBase64`? can you give an example?

Comment: @callback its in base64 format and it may contain any image format such as svg or png etc..

Comment: Can you show one example?

Comment: @callback added example, can you look in to this once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to create a function that first decodes the encoded string, and then extracts the type from the decoded string provided a finite set of type options.

```
getType(imageBase64) { 
    let extension = undefined; 
    const decodedString = window.atob(imageBase64); //decode the string;
    const lowerCase = decodedString.toLowerCase();
    // find the extension in the decoded string
    if (lowerCase.indexOf("png") !== -1) extension = "png"
    else if (lowerCase.indexOf("svg") !== -1) extension = "svg+xml"
    else if (lowerCase.indexOf("jpg") !== -1 || lowerCase.indexOf("jpeg") !== -1)
        extension = "jpg"
    // add more cases if needed..
    return extension;
}
```

Then use this function in your template.

```
<img *ngIf="imageBase64" [src]="imageBase64 ? ('data:image/' + getType(imageBase64) + ';base64,' +imageBase64 | safe) : ''" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thats works fine, is there any other way to proceed, so that we can handle it all from HTML, instead of .ts

Comment: @AnilKumarReddyA, since it is necessary to decode and check for string occurrence, it is not recommended to have all that logic in the template. Especially that you have to access the window object, which is not possible from the template, unless you define it in the .ts file anyway. So either way, you have to use the .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img *ngIf="imageBase64" [src]="imageBase64.base64">
```